# How to retain footer text but remove page number for IEEE Conference format

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran, ieeeconf

I'm facing a problem with IEEE conference LaTeX template on overleaf. The final submission requires a footer in the first page, but the page numbers are to be removed from all pages. The footer is 979-8-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/$31.00 ©2023 IEEE. I have used fancyhdr package and tried \thispagestyle{empty} to remove page numbers from pages 2-6. If i use \thispagestyle{empty} in the first page, the entire footer including the copyright gets removed. However, I would like to retain the copyright footer in the first page, but remove the page number from the footer. The MWE is below. Could someone please guide me with this?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\title{My paper title}
\maketitle
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Keyword1, keyword2, keyword3.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\lfoot{\ifnum\value{page}<2\small 979-8-xxxx-xxxx-x/xx/ \$31.00  \copyright$\;$ 2023 IEEE\else\fi}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[1]\\

\lipsum[2]\\

\lipsum[3]\\

\lipsum[4]\\

\lipsum[5]\\

\lipsum[6]\\

\lipsum[7]\\

\lipsum[8]\\

\lipsum[9]\\

\lipsum[10]\\
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Is the footer explicitly required in the instructions for authors of the conference? I ask this because usually, this copyright footer is added by IEEE themselves (as well as the page numbering) when processing the proceedings.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the quick response. To answer your question, yes, the conference guidelines have an explicit note that the authors have to add the copyright footer before the final submission. It says, "Please affix the appropriate copyright clearance code notice at the bottom of the first column of the first page of paper according to guidelines set forth in the Cataloging/Copyright Instructions for an IEEE Conference Proceeding." The guidelines then proceed to give the actual copyright number.

Comment: It does! It worked like a charm! Thank you very much for the timely help.